# Customise Publishing Options based on Role

Tags: nodes

Is there a simple way to customise the Publishing options so that certain Roles are only able to create content but not publish it. I have tried the Workflow and Workbench modules but they are way too complicated!

Answer (score 1):

The [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) module automatically generates separate create, edit, and publish permissions by role for all content types for which revison control is enabled.  It also integrates with the Rules module.  You may find this to be a simpler approach.